# Missing text on toolbar buttons in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, button

For some reason the text is missing on all the toolbar buttons in LibreOffice Writer.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried to uninstall and install it again, but it hasn't worked. Any idea what could be wrong?